# How to use "pycimport" module of Jython?

Tags: python, jython, pyc

I want to import a pyc file in Jython, and I was suggested to explore the 'pycimport' module in Jython, but since this is an experimental module , I was not able to get any code examples, I would be very glad if anybody can help me to implement this module in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to implement the `pycimport` module in Java?

Using the `pycimport` module is actually quite simple, you just import the module, and after that you can import modules in pyc-files:

```
cole:tmp tobias$ cat mymodule.py
def fibonacci(n):
    a,b = 1,0
    for i in range(n):
        a,b = a+b,a
    return a

cole:tmp tobias$ python
Python 2.7 (r27:82508, Jul  3 2010, 21:12:11) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from mymodule import fibonacci
>>> fibonacci(4)
5
>>> fibonacci(5)
8
>>> ^D
cole:tmp tobias$ ls mymodule.*
mymodule.py mymodule.pyc
cole:tmp tobias$ mv mymodule.py xmymodule.pyx
cole:tmp tobias$ jython
Jython 2.5.2rc4 (trunk:7202, Feb 24 2011, 14:31:12) 
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Apple Inc.)] on java1.6.0_26
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pycimport
>>> from mymodule import fibonacci
>>> fibonacci(4)
5
>>> fibonacci(5)
8
>>> ^D
```

Just to show that `pycimport` does infact import from the pyc-file:

```
cole:tmp tobias$ jython
Jython 2.5.2rc4 (trunk:7202, Feb 24 2011, 14:31:12) 
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Apple Inc.)] on java1.6.0_26
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mymodule
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mymodule
>>> import pycimport              
>>> import mymodule 
>>> mymodule.__file__
'mymodule.pyc'
>>> ^D
```

As you note though, the `pycimport` module is experimental. I don't think anyone has touched it since I wrote it 4 years ago. A few things have changed in the Jython internals that `pycimport` uses since then, so there might be a few issues in it. It could be fun to revisit that code, but I don't know when I would have time, so I will not make any promises.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it :)

The pyc file named shams.pyc is located at C:\PyTest\ and its corresponding .py file's contents are as follows:

#### shams.py

```
class test:

    def call_helloworld(self) :
        return "Hello World"
```

#### test.java

```
import org.python.core.PyObject;
import org.python.core.PyString;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

import org.python.core.PyObject;
import org.python.core.PyString;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;
public class test{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
        PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(),System.getProperties(), new String[0]); 
        interpreter.exec("import sys");
        interpreter.exec("sys.path.append('C:\\PyTest')"); 
        interpreter.exec("import pycimport");
        interpreter.exec("import shams");
        interpreter.exec("from shams import test");
        PyObject pyClass = interpreter.get("test");
        PyString real_result = (PyString) pyClass.invoke("call_helloworld",pyClass.__call__());
        System.out.println(real_result);
    }
}
```